# How add extra class on Jquery Datatable pagination anchor element?

Tags: jquery, pagination, datatables

I have following structure, I just want add an extra class on every anchor element

```
<ul class="pagination">
    <li class="paginate_button page-item previous disabled" aria-controls="users" tabindex="0" id="users_previous">
        <a href="#">Prev</a>
    </li>
    <li class="paginate_button page-item active" aria-controls="users" tabindex="0">
        <a href="#">1</a>
    </li>
    <li class="paginate_button page-item next disabled" aria-controls="users" tabindex="0" id="users_next">
        <a href="#">Next</a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Thanks,
Kaleem

Comment: `$('a').addClass('myNewClassName')` will do that for you

Comment: isn't any callback or any other way to add while rendering pagination?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [dataTables assigning a css class to the pagination wrapper](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21521761/datatables-assigning-a-css-class-to-the-pagination-wrapper) - you can adapt this to do what you want

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can easily add a class on every anchor tag like so:

```
$('.pagination a').addClass('myNewClassName');
```

This will only add them within the parent with class `pagination`

To do it the datatables way:

```
$('#myDataTable').DataTable({
    ...
    "drawCallback": function () {
        $('.dataTables_paginate > .pagination a').addClass('myNewClassName');
    }
});
```

[Modified from this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21521761/datatables-assigning-a-css-class-to-the-pagination-wrapper)

Answer (score -1):

Try it

```js
$('#Mytable').DataTable({
addClassFunction(); // call this function in DataTable/pagination method
});

function addClassFunction(){
$('.pagination a').addClass('newClass');
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="pagination">
    <li class="paginate_button page-item previous disabled" aria-controls="users" tabindex="0" id="users_previous">
        <a href="#">Prev</a>
    </li>
    <li class="paginate_button page-item active" aria-controls="users" tabindex="0">
        <a href="#">1</a>
    </li>
    <li class="paginate_button page-item next disabled" aria-controls="users" tabindex="0" id="users_next">
        <a href="#">Next</a>
    </li>
</ul>
```